Is SCTP multihoming supported by Linux IPVS?
I have configured a VIP with 2 real servers behind it. There is a remote client with SCTP Multihoming enabled(with 2 ip address - primary and secondary). Here sctp association created between 2 client ip addresses and VIP. Now connection is on real-server-1 and messages are forwarded to the same. When primary address goes down, secondary address starts sending the messages but IPVS forwarding it to real-server-2 instead of real-server-1 and connection is getting closed.
Is it possible or is there anyway to forward the message to same real server in this case?
Note: When messages forwarded to real-server-1 by IPVS, then no issues seen i.e., message exchange is successful.
IPVS version : IPVS v1.2.1
